# Shopify GraphQL customerCreate mutation requires password?

Tags: rest, graphql, shopify

I am using Shopify's GraphQL mutations in order to create a customer on a button click on the front end of my website. The user is prompted for an email, on submit, they will receive an email to activate their account. The "customerCreate" mutation in the documentation does not state that password is required, however my API response states that a password is required in my post request, can anyone help me to create an account without requiring a password? Here is the [shopify documentation](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-10/mutations/customercreate). Thank you in advance for any help

```
mutation customerCreate($input: CustomerCreateInput!) {
      customerCreate(input: $input) {
        customerUserErrors {
          code
          field
          message
        }
        customer {
          id
        }
      }
    }


    {
      "input": {
        "email": "example@gmail.com",
        "acceptsMarketing": true
      }
    }
```

Error message:
"message": "Variable $input of type CustomerCreateInput! was provided invalid value for password (Expected value to not be null)",

Comment: Shopify Plus has multipass which doesn't require password

Answer (score 0):

The backend Admin API mutation has no such restriction. You are speaking specifically of the Storefront API mutation then, which means when you are creating customers, you're doing it while they are present in the store itself. Since they are present in the store itself, why don't you collect their desired password, and send that along to the mutation? You can surely present a form with a text field. That way, you satisfy the mutation.

Straight from the docs here... you are on the front-end of a website, so you have no choice but to use Storefront API: https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/2022-10/mutations/customerCreate